# Shell script for Grepping/retrieving value from text log file (sqlcode field value)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, sqlcode

Hello I have the need to retrieve the sqlcode value from the outfiles that are generated after running sql statements.

The following value of the sqlcode below is obviously 0 and i would need to be able to grab that value from multiple blocks of statements formatted like below.

I cannot use GNU functions - grep/sed/awk may work but i havent been able to grab the sqlcode value using them myself...

Outfile will look like the following:

```
SQLCA Information

sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: 0   sqlerrml: 0

sqlerrmc:

 sqlerrp : SQLRI01F

sqlerrd : (1) -2147221503      (2) 1                (3) 4

           (4) 0                (5) 0                (6) 0

sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)

           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)       (11)

sqlstate: 00000
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework question... [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow). You are expected to make an effort.

Comment: Please edit  your Q to show your best attempt to solve the problem.(what you think should work); We can't help you improve your understanding if we don't know what you have tried. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/sqlcode: /s/.*sqlcode: \([0-9]\+\) .*/\1/p'
```

If the line has the string "sqlcode: ", then substitute everything and remember one or more numbers after the string "sqlcode: " and before a space and print that remembered part.

Live version available at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/ihagqv).

Comment: thanks for the answer..i see how this works but....
I wrapped the sed in a variable in a script
var=$(sed -n '/sqlcode: /s/.*sqlcode: \([0-9]\+\) .*/\1/p' file.out) 
and when i implement this in a script on the linux AIX server with the file.out in the same directory it returns nothing...which i dont quite understand

ive tried running it as shell and bash

Answer (score 0):

**awk   '/sqlcode/  {print  $7}'     file**

0

awk looks in the file for the default value / sqlcode /

print $ 7 prints the seventh field